# How to use JavaFX FilteredList in a ListView?

Tags: listview, javafx, filtering

I have a ListView in my application which contains Strings.
Now, I want to filter this list by an input field. But all examples about FilteredLists I found are about how to filter a table.

How can I filter a ListView using a FilteredList?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is rather simple and straightforward:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).mapToObj(Integer::toString).forEach(data::add);

    FilteredList<String> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, s -> true);

    TextField filterInput = new TextField();
    filterInput.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
        String filter = filterInput.getText(); 
        if(filter == null || filter.length() == 0) {
            filteredData.setPredicate(s -> true);
        }
        else {
            filteredData.setPredicate(s -> s.contains(filter));
        }
    });


    BorderPane content = new BorderPane(new ListView<>(filteredData));
    content.setBottom(filterInput);

    Scene scene = new Scene(content, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Can this be achieved without using Lambda experssions ? My java project is built on Java7. Thanks.

Comment: @SachinGadagi Of course. In the simplest case: Just replace the lambas with anonymous inner classes.

Comment: I love lambdas, it can even be more simplified to `filteredData.setPredicate(newValue.isEmpty() ? s -> true : s -> s.getKey().contains(newValue));`

Comment: Instead of `s -> true` one can also set `null` as predicate, because that will default to a match-all predicate according to the javadoc

Comment: For multiple fields filtering, the answer in this link will help .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325565/3056868

Comment: @eckig but how do we filter existing filled `ObservableList` ? .In your case you create a `new ListView ()` ,in my case I have a filled `ListView`.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Please file a new question for this

Comment: But it also means that we create new predicate on every text/char change. I know internet full of such examples, but is there a better way to avoid creating the new predicate (aka object) on every input change? It would be much nicer if we could just initialize the predicate with the binding property (like text field property) and refresh/invalidate the filter on the change, so we can use single and only one predicate object to do all the filtering.