# JavaFX FilteredList, filtering based on property of items in the list

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a case where I need to filter a `ObservableList<Item>` based on some properties of the items (i.e. the condition is internal and not external). I found out that javafx has `FilteredList` so I tried it. I could set the predicate and filtering works, until the property value that determines the filtering changes. Setting the predicate is done now like following:

```
list.setPredicate(t -> !t.filteredProperty().get())
```

Since the predicate returns boolean and not BooleanProperty, the changes to that property are not reflected on the list.

Is there any easy solution to this? I could try to do some workarounds, e.g. create a separate list and sync that, or reset the predicate every time the property changes in one item hopefully retriggering the filtering, but I first wanted to ask in case someone knows a pretty solution as those workarounds certainly are not.

Comment: When you are changing the property, just make a call to `list.setPredicate(t -> !t.filteredProperty().get())` again.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The list is part of a model that is updated whenever there is new data. The view displaying the data does not know when this happens, but I guess I can make that as a event from the model somehow ... I guess there is no practical way of doing this kind of stuff from just the list since I would need to add e.g. a InvalidationListener to every item/property in the list.

Comment: `FXCollections` has a factory method that creates such an invalidation listener for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create the underlying list with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-). This will enable the underlying list to fire update events when the `filteredProperty()` of any elements change. The `FilteredList` will observe these events and so will update accordingly:

```
ObservableList<Item> baseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> 
    new Observable[] {item.filteredProperty()});
FilteredList<Item> list = new FilteredList<>(baseList, t -> ! t.filteredProperty().get());
```

Quick demo:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;


public class DynamicFilteredListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObservableList<Item> baseList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> 
                new Observable[] {item.filteredProperty()});

        FilteredList<Item> list = new FilteredList<>(baseList, t -> ! t.isFiltered());

        list.addListener((Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println(c.getAddedSubList()+ " added to filtered list");
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    System.out.println(c.getRemoved()+ " removed from filtered list");
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Adding ten items to base list:\n");

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i)).forEach(baseList::add);

        System.out.println("\nFiltered list now:\n"+list);

        System.out.println("\nSetting filtered flag for alternate items in base list:\n");

        IntStream.range(0, 5).map(i -> 2*i).mapToObj(baseList::get).forEach(i -> i.setFiltered(true));

        System.out.println("\nFiltered list now:\n"+list);
    }


    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
        private final BooleanProperty filtered = new SimpleBooleanProperty() ;

        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final BooleanProperty filteredProperty() {
            return this.filtered;
        }

        public final boolean isFiltered() {
            return this.filteredProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFiltered(final boolean filtered) {
            this.filteredProperty().set(filtered);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, just works :), thanks! On small note, this seems to only work when the actual list is not wrapped in a FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList (my model was read-only outside of the place where it is updated from data). After using the actualy list instead of the unmodifiable wrapping this works. Good enough for me :)

Comment: That looks like a bug; however note that a `FilteredList` is unmodifiable anyway, so if you can only expose the `FilteredList` you can achieve the same degree of encapsulation.

Comment: Is it possible to set two properties in the extractor? I'd like to create two `FilteredList`, but each one should filter a different property.

Comment: Just solved it: `new javafx.beans.Observable[] {item.filteredProperty1(), item.filteredProperty2()});`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using database loading function plus need to filter multiple fields, this solution will help.

```
 ObservableList<PurchaseOrder> poData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 FilteredList<PurchaseOrder> filteredData;
  private void load()  {
        PurchaseOrder po = new PurchaseOrder();
        try {
            poData = po.loadTable("purchase_orders", beanFields); // Database loading data
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PurchaseOrdersController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        filteredData = new FilteredList<>(poData, t -> true); //Encapsulate data with filter

        poTable.setItems(filteredData); //Load filtered data into table

        //Set event trigger for all filter textboxes
        txtFilter.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
            filter(filteredData);
        });
        txtFilter2.textProperty().addListener(obs->{
            filter(filteredData);
        });
  }

   private void filter(FilteredList<PurchaseOrder> filteredData)
    {
            filteredData.setPredicate(PurchaseOrder -> {
                // If all filters are empty then display all Purchase Orders
                if ((txtFilter.getText() == null || txtFilter.getText().isEmpty()) 
                        && (txtFilter2.getText() == null || txtFilter2.getText().isEmpty())) {
                    return true;
                }

                // Convert filters to lower case
                String lowerCaseFilter = txtFilter.getText().toLowerCase();
                String lowerCaseFilter2 = txtFilter2.getText().toLowerCase();

                //If fails any given criteria, fail completely
                if(txtFilter.getText().length()>0)
                    if (PurchaseOrder.get("vendor_name").toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter) == false)
                        return false;
                if(txtFilter2.getText().length()>0)
                    if (PurchaseOrder.get("PONumber").toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter2) == false)
                        return false;

                return true; // Matches given criteria
            });
    }
```