# Javafx: Incorrect usage of setPredicate method of a filtered list

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableView that contains an observable list of `Person` items. Each row displays a `Person` object and its `name` attribute is also displayed.

I want to pass this observable into a filtered list and **set the predicate on the name attribute**.

What I want to achieve is that:
If I double click any one row in the TableView that contains `Person` items, I would be able to extract the `names` attributes of the selected `Person` object and **set the predicate of the filtered list to be the selected name**.

So the filtered list will only contain `Person` items with the selected name.

The following code almost achieve everything I want. However, there is an **edge case** where it does not work as expected. This is when for example, I double click on the person with "name = John". The filtered list will filter all the person with name "John". Now, if I change one of the person's name within the filtered list to "Tim". This person is still retained in the filtered list. Ideally, I want it to be removed **automatically**. **But I am not able to do so.**

I believe that I am not using `setPredicate` correctly, as I feel like I am writing redundant codes and there should be more efficient way to do this and will automatically **remove Person with a different name right after Edit**.

Within my `Person` class,

```
private StringProperty Name;
private final BooleanProperty filteredName = new SimpleBooleanProperty() ;  

public final boolean getFilteredName(){
    return filteredNameProperty().getValue();
}

public final BooleanProperty filteredNameProperty(){
    return this.filteredName;
}

public final void setFilteredName(String name){
    if(getName().equals(name)){
        this.filteredNameProperty().set(true);
    } else{
        this.filteredNameProperty().set(false);
    }
}
```

Within my Controller, I have:

```
        private ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson = FXCollections.observableArrayList(p->
        new Observable[]{
                p.nameProperty(),
                p.filteredNameProperty()
        }
    );
        private FilteredList<Person> filterListOfPerson= new FilteredList<>(observableListOfPerson, p-> p.filteredNameProperty().get());

public void initializeFilteredTable(){
        filteredTab.setText("Filtered History");
        filterTable.setItems(filterListOfPerson);

        filterListOfPerson.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Person>(){
              @Override
                public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
                  filterTable.setItems(filterListOfPerson);
              }
        });
        filterTable.setItems(filterListOfPerson);}
```

Within my `AnimatedRow` class, I have:

```
public class AnimatedRow<T> extends TableRow<T> {
    private TabPane fxTabPaneLower;

    /**
     * The data as an observable list of Person.
     */
    private ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson;
    private FilteredList<Person> filterListOfPerson;

    public AnimatedRow(Function<T, StringExpression> nameExtractor, ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson, FilteredList<Person> filterListOfPerson, TabPane fxTabPaneLower) {
                   setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!isEmpty()) ) {
                final StringExpression nameBE = nameExtractor.apply(getItem());
                for(Person t : observableListOfPerson){
                    t.setFilteredName(nameBE.get());

                }
                filterListOfPerson.setPredicate(p-> p.filteredNameProperty().get());

                fxTabPaneLower.getSelectionModel().select(1);
                ((TableView<Person>)fxTabPaneLower.getTabs().get(1).getContent()).setItems(filterListOfPerson);              
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to filter the list on the commit of the update of the name?

Comment: @purringpigeon No, you just need to ensure the underlying list fires updates when the property changes.

Comment: I had a look at that question before I posted this question and I did exactly everything in the answer you posted for the question. I added `new ObservableList[] {p -> p.NameProperty()....}`

Comment: Yes, I missed that initially. I don't really get the purpose of `filteredName`. Are you using that for anything other than filtering?

Comment: Basically, `filteredListOfPerson` is my second table view. So if I click Person's name in the first table view, which contains all the Person items, the `filteredListOfPerson` will filter all the Person items from the first table by the selected name and display the results in the second table view. This all worked fine until I started editing the Person item in the second table, then I realised if I changed a Person's name in the `filteredListOfPerson`, it will still remain in the second table.

Comment: I meant: what is `filteredName` for: I understand what `filteredListOfPerson` is for. In the question I temporarily linked, it doesn't say anything about adding boolean properties to your entity class representing whether the item is filtered. Why don't you try it the way it was done in that example?

Comment: Oh. Sorry I misread it. `filteredName` is an additional property for checking whether the Person has the same name as the `name` selected on double click. This is why every Person item will have a boolean property. I was inspired by your answer in the other question and created that. I do not know how to improve on that.

Comment: But my other answer doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I think I did not fully  understand the question the user was asking. And I was confused as to how to initiailize the `FilteredList` because   it can only take in boolean arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is essentially a duplicate of [JavaFX FilteredList, filtering based on property of items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915007/javafx-filteredlist-filtering-based-on-property-of-items-in-the-list).)

It looks like you are trying to implement filtering in your `Person` class. The whole point of a `FilteredList` is that it implements the filter for you.

So I think you just get rid of the `filteredName` property entirely and then do

```
public AnimatedRow(Function<T, StringExpression> nameExtractor, ObservableList<Person> observableListOfPerson, FilteredList<Person> filterListOfPerson, TabPane fxTabPaneLower) {
    setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!isEmpty()) ) {
            final StringExpression nameBE = nameExtractor.apply(getItem());
            filterListOfPerson.setPredicate(p-> p.getName().equals(nameBE.get()));

            fxTabPaneLower.getSelectionModel().select(1);
            ((TableView<Person>)fxTabPaneLower.getTabs().get(1).getContent()).setItems(filterListOfPerson);              
        }
    });
}
```

As long as you have the name property returned as part of the extractor for the underlying list, the filter will get re-evaluated when the name changes.

Comment: How would you initialize the filteredList in this case, since it needs to take in a boolean argument ?

Comment: [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) does not "take in a boolean argument". It expects an `ObservableList` and a `Predicate`.

Comment: I mean in my Controller class, when I initialize the filtered List, I did this: `private FilteredList<Person> filterListOfPerson = new FilteredList<>(observableListOfPerson, p-> p.nameProperty().get());`  . And it complains that Type mismatch: String cannot be converted to boolean. I remembered this is why I created the boolean property in the first place.

Comment: The second argument is the (initial) `Predicate`. Just give it the `Predicate` representing how you want the items to be initially filtered. (Frankly, you are sounding like you are just blindly copying code without any actual idea what it is doing. How can you expect a function returning a name (i.e. `String`) to define a filter?)

Comment: I was not blindly copying the code. I did not fully understand the `setPredicate` method. If I was blindly copying the code, I would not have created the booleanProperty and manually create the filtering steps.

Comment: Well, that's fair. But if you had taken the time to understand how it worked, you wouldn't have created it either :). But just give it the initial predicate you want to use.

Comment: Yes. I did that. Thanks. I am not a CS major. And I learned programming on my own. That's why my basics are poor. Hope you can understand that.