# Dynamically update list of checkbox based on changing date (value)

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a simple checklist with starting dates that responds to a time slider that specifies a date.

- Each task has a start date.
- Each task checkbox should only be rendered if the task start date has elapsed.

The checklist looks like this on initialize

[image: checklist with time slider]

How do i update the checklist to respond to the time slider?

I understand I need to add a listener somewhere or make a call to update the ui elements in the scene somewhere, but I am unsure where to begin.

I have tried updating the list used to create, but it doesn't update the UI elements because they have already been created.

ProjectChecklist.java

```
public class ProjectChecklist extends Application {
  Group root = new Group();
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
  VBox vbox = new VBox();
  HBox hbox = new HBox();
  ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();


  taskList = getAllTasks(PROJECT_FILENAME);
  todayDate = LocalDate.now();
  sliderStartDate = taskList.get(0).getStartDate();
  LocalDate sliderEndDate = taskList.get(taskList.size() - 1).getEndDate();

  long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(sliderStartDate, sliderEndDate);
  long daysFromToday = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(sliderStartDate, todayDate);

  slider = new Slider(0, days, 1);
  slider.setValue(daysFromToday);
  sliderValue = new Label(LocalDate.now().toString());
  slider.setMajorTickUnit(1);
  slider.setShowTickLabels(true);

  scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
  scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

  slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    double daysValue = Math.round(newValue.doubleValue());
    LocalDate newDate = (sliderStartDate.plusDays((long) daysValue));
    slider.setValue(daysValue);
    sliderValue.setText(newDate.toString());
  }
  int taskNumber = 1;

  for (ChecklistTask task : taskList) {
    if (!task.getStartDate().isAfter(todayDate)) {
      CheckBox newCB = new CheckBox();
      newCB.setText("task " + taskNumber++ + ": " + task.getDescription());
      vbox.getChildren().add(newCB);
    }
  }
  vbox.getChildren().add(slider);
  vbox.getChildren().add(sliderValue);
  hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);
  hbox.setSpacing(40);
  hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

  scrollPane.setContent(hbox);
  scrollPane.setPrefSize(600, 300);
  scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);

  root.getChildren().add(scrollPane);

  primaryStage.setTitle("Bennington checklist");
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  launch(args);
  runApplication();
}
```

ChecklistTask.java

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ChecklistTask{
    private UUID id;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    public ChecklistTask() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: the link to the image is broken, please edit it

Comment: anyway, you have to add/remove/configure the checkBox in your listener .. don't quite understand where the problem is, exactly?

Comment: @kleopatra link is fixed

Comment: yeah have seen it, but what's the problem?

Comment: adjusting the slider does not change the checklist currently, I want the list of checkboxes to update when the slider is moved to only include tasks that have started

Comment: what do you expect - you are not coding anything to change them ;) Please re-read my comment carefully, it tells you what do do where ..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a ListView which is backed by a FilteredList where the predicate compares the slider value to the ChequelistTask date.  Changing the value of the slider will automatically update the predicate for filtering the list where the start date > the selected date of the slider.  The filtering will take care of the list being updated accordingly, without having to rebuild the VBox content.

Here's an example of updating a predicate when something changes:
[JavaFX FilteredList, filtering based on property of items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915007/javafx-filteredlist-filtering-based-on-property-of-items-in-the-list)