# How to filter and show in VBox

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

Could anyone suggest how could i do this to show the Dynamic template in `VBox`. Below is my code and i would like to wrap the sortedlist into the `SearchVBox` so it could show the Dynamic template which the users search. At the most bottom i have provided the example of what i need to do.

```
public class UserSearchController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField filterField;   
    @FXML
    private VBox SearchVbox;

    private static final String productFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Cre8\\Desktop\\APU prgram\\APU sem3\\OODJ\\Product.txt";
    List<CSVproduct> csvProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    ObservableList<CSVproduct> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(csvProducts);
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        try {
            addUserSearchNewPane();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewProduct.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    

    void addUserSearchNewPane() throws IOException{
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(productFilePath));
        CsvToBean<CSVproduct> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(CSVproduct.class)
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .build();
        csvProducts = csvToBean.parse();
        for (CSVproduct csvproduct : csvProducts) {
        UserSearchTemplateController usersearchTC = new UserSearchTemplateController();
        System.out.println(csvproduct.getProductName());
        usersearchTC.setSearchName(csvproduct.getProductName());
        usersearchTC.setSearchPrice(csvproduct.getProductPrice());
        usersearchTC.setSearchQuantity(csvproduct.getProductQuantity());
        usersearchTC.setSearchRate(csvproduct.getProductRate());
        usersearchTC.setSearchDescription(csvproduct.getProductDescription());
        usersearchTC.setSearchImage(csvproduct.getProductImage());
        this.SearchVbox.getChildren().add(usersearchTC);
        }
    }
    void UserFilterFunction(){
        FilteredList<CSVproduct> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, p -> true);
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(csvproduct -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (csvproduct.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true;
                } 
                return false;
            });
        });
        SortedList<CSVproduct> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        this.SearchVbox.getChildren().add(sortedData);//how do i show the sortedlist insde the SearchVbox.
    }
}
```

The last line of code doesn't work. [Like this example to filter and show the dynamic VBox template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSOdS.png)

Comment: Try [`ListView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448851/how-to-use-javafx-filteredlist-in-a-listview